# Can you smoothly change speed of video in FCPX

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I know it's easy to change a part of a video to be slow-motion or time-lapse by using "speed" setting. But what if I'd like to gradually slow down or speed up over the course of two-three seconds?

I know I can cut the video 5 times and change the speed of individual sub-parts, but maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to your speed marker are greyish areas. These areas can be adjusted and you can use that to make the transition to the speed change as long as you want. 
[image: Exsample Screenshot]